# <hr> property styling issue

Tags: html, css

I have a container div for my website with the following CSS code

```
.container {
    width: 1020px;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and it has a fixed width as it is shown above. In the container there is a navbar and a section in between of those I am using an `<hr>` property in order to separate them, but the issue I am having is even if I will give this hr a 100% width it will fit just the width of my container, but I want it to expand through out the whole page.

Is there any way to manage that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably better off using a border but I'm not sure what you're going for

Comment: show us the html that goes with your css, please.

Comment: Is the nav bar a fixed height?

Comment: An imperfect solution could be [absolute positioning with left & right at 0](http://jsfiddle.net/rcSXW/), but that means it's outside the flow and you have to space your items manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element's width, when given relative sizing, is relative to its parent element. In this case, then, there's no way to have the `hr` element's `width` be relative to another parent.

You can, though, give a width of greater than `100%`, and then use a negative margin to centre, if required:

```
​div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
}

​div hr {
    width: 190%;
    margin-left: -45%;
}​

<div id="a">
    <hr />
</div>​
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hEaUx/).

Comment: This is a kind of a workaround but the only problem with that, is the resizing of the window. Whenever it happens the line goes way off the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you're better off not setting a width or margin on the container, but on the contents themselves. Should be straightforward if you have a simple HTML structure inside that container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container p { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cEGNb/1/